# Remove Database Duplicates with Similar Name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a database that stores the name of the image files where they can be retrieved from on the server.

The table description is as follows:

```
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id         | varchar(50)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| userid     | varchar(8)      | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| albumid    | varchar(25)     | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| image_name | varchar(256)    | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| status     | int(1) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| comments   | varchar(4000)   | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| mod_date   | timestamp       | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

I have a separate PHP script that scans the image folders for new files and adds them to the database.
However, someone who was trying to update the database deleted all the folders (for every single userid and albumid...) along with all the old images and recreated all folder with a set of new images with new names.

This left the website displaying broken picture links of the old set of images but with all the status and comments made on there, while the new set of images displays correctly but with no status and comment information stored.

Out of all the fields in the table. The only fields in the table that tells the old and new apart are the `id`, `mod_date` (which are both automatically generated) and the `image_name`.

The image name both share the same string but is pre-pended with different paths information.

Example:

old image name: `XXX_02420624_20100308-00231_A.png`

new image name: `YYY_02420624_20100308-00231_A.png`

Notice that `02420624_20100308-00231_A.png`  are being shared by both old and new with different pre-pends.

My question is.. if not all the albums are being updated (i.e. even though all the folders for all users and all albums are deleted and then added back, not all of them have new file names), what is the most efficient way of removing these duplicate data and still keep the comments and status assigned for each image?

I figure I can delete the new rows of images and rename the old image name into the new one so it points correctly to the right image and still retains the status/comments. However, how do I write a general script that search for the new images that are automatically stored in the DB?

**EDIT:** The newly added image names has the format of

> yyy_userid_albumid_AAA.png

where `yyy` is the pre-pend identical for all new images, `userid` and `albumid` pretty much self-explanatory, and `AAA` is the unique image name.

Since I know the `xxx` and `yyy` are both constants, I can write a script in php that automatically looks through the database and delete the entries that has image_name beginning with `yyy` and then change the `xxx` to `yyy` so that the image points to the right path and still retains the status and comment. My question is: how can you write a script that only search within the string of '`image_name`' for the pre-pend until it hit the 8 digit `userid` (that starts with 0)?

Comment: What have you tried to this point?  Or at least what thoughts do you have on how you might approach this?

Comment: Since I know the xxx and yyy are both constants, I can write a script in php that automatically looks through the database and delete the entries that has image_name beginning with yyy and then change the xxx to yyy so that the image points to the right path and still retains the status and comment. My question is: how can you write a script that only search within the string of 'image_name' for the pre-pend until it hit the 8 digit userid (that starts with 0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to link the new names to the old images' records.

The SQL below should update the image names of all the old 'xxx' images with new image names. You will then just have to delete the new records which were added (ones prefixed with yyy)

(untested)

```
update the_table t 
set t.image_name = 
(select COALESCE(t2.image_name,t.image_name) 
from the_table t2 
where = t2.image_name = 'yyy' || substring(t.image_name,<size of xxx>))
```

Comment: Could you clarify your code within the parenthesis? `(select t2.image_name 
from the_table t2 
where substring(t.image_name,<size of xxx>) = substring(t2.image_name,<size of yyy>)
and t2.image_name = 'yyy' || substring(t2.image_name,<size of yyy>))`

where substring = substring, i think these will be identical?

Comment: I modified it slightly to remove that filter.  Let me know if it makes more sense now.  The coalesce will use t.image_name (old) if a new version doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I understand the general idea of the statement, but there are some errors. `Where t2.image_name = 'yyy'` and shouldn't the `|| (or)` be an append instead?

Comment: That was supposed to be an append, yes.

Comment: I get this error `ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause`. I think it doesn't allow calling from the same table in the FROM statement, any work around?

Comment: Check this out. I'll try to update the comment tonight but this may help. It seems you may be able to join the select and the_table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402678/mysql-update-from-select-same-table