# How to update rows using results from the same table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, insert-update

How to update rows using results from the same table in mysql?

like this...

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang`
   SET `description` = (
         SELECT `description`
           FROM `ps_product_lang`
          WHERE `id_product` = 300003)
WHERE `id_product` = 300003
```

i'm getting the error

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'ps_product_lang' for update
>   in FROM clause

1. can i do it on MySQL ?
2. what is the right query ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql update from select - same table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402678/mysql-update-from-select-same-table)

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN:

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang AS p1
CROSS JOIN ps_product_lang AS p2
SET p1.description = p2.description
WHERE p1.id_product = 300003
AND p2.id_product = 300003
```

Did you really mean to use the same `id_product` in both the source and destination? That won't do anything.

Comment: UPDATE ps_product_lang AS p1
CROSS JOIN ps_product_lang AS p2
SET p1.description = p2.description
WHERE p1.id_product = 300003 and `id_lang` =3
AND p2.id_product = 300003 and `id_lang` =1
 like this ??

Comment: I don't see anything about the different languages in your original query.

Answer (score 0):

sorry ,

this is the answer :

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang AS p1
CROSS JOIN ps_product_lang AS p2
SET p1.description = p2.description
WHERE p1.id_product = 300003 and p1.`id_lang` =3
AND p2.id_product = 300003 and p2.`id_lang` =1
```

Barmar - THANKS ! :)