# How does MySQL update the fields value in the same table?

Tags: mysql

- test 1:

  update tb_chapters t set t.order_id = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM tb_chapters t2 WHERE t.bid = t2.bid AND t.id > t2.id)

error: 
`1093 - You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause`

---

- test 2:

  update tb_chapters t set t.order_id = (SELECT t2.c FROM (SELECT COUNT(t1.id) AS c FROM tb_chapters t1 WHERE t1.bid = t.bid AND t1.id < t.id) AS t2)

error:
`1054 - Unknown column 't.bid' in 'where clause'`

---

- test 3:

  update tb_chapters AS t JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS c FROM tb_chapters t1 WHERE t1.bid = t.bid AND t1.id < t.id) AS t2 USING(id) set t.order_id = t2.c

error:
`1054 - Unknown column 't.bid' in 'where clause'`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Some sample data with expected output will be helpful. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402678/mysql-update-from-select-same-table

Answer (score 0):

- You can first take `bid` and corresponding expected Count value in a [derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). And,
- Now, `Join` that derived table with the base table again, and use `Update` based on the two tables.
- **Note** that I have changed your `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, so that it will update **0** as count for the cases where there is no other `id`, less than the `id` for a particular `bid`.
- Utilizing [Ifnull()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function, we can check if a value is `Null` and set it to some another value (in this case, setting to 0 for the bid(s) discussed in previous point.

Try the following:

```
UPDATE tb_chapters AS t3 
JOIN 
(
SELECT t1.bid, IFNULL(COUNT(t2.id), 0) AS c
FROM tb_chapters AS t1 
LEFT JOIN tb_chapters AS t2 ON t2.bid = t1.bid 
                                AND t2.id < t1.id 
GROUP BY t1.bid 
) AS t4 ON t4.bid = t3.bid 

SET t3.order_id = t4.c
```